# Facebook DIV alignment in page

Tags: css, facebook, html, alignment

Hi Im having some issues with a alignment issue with a facebook feed page on our front page website.

all of the secions are meant to be alinged into the centre, or left atleast and have padding betweeen them to make it look even, but the facebook one keeps pushing up to the instagram feed with no padding

the website is located at braaap-dev.3dcartstores.com and the code in questions is below:

```
<!--START: FRAME_MAILLIST-->
<form method="post" name="mailing" action="mailing_list.asp?action=add" onsubmit="return mailing_list();" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;margin-bottom:12px;">
<div style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-weight: bold; ">Sign-up to our weekly newsletter & stay up to date<br>with events, promotions & specials!</span></div>
<div style="padding:10px 0px;"><input name="email" type="text" class="txtBoxStyle" value="enter your email" size="18" onfocus="javascript:if (document.mailing.email.value=='enter your email') {document.mailing.email.value='';};" onblur="if(this.value.length == 0) this.value = 'enter your email'" style="font-size:12px;width:315px;padding:8px 14px;_padding:10px 14px 6px 14px;padding:10px 14px 6px 14px\0;padding:10px 14px 6px 14px\9;"></div>
<div><input name="subscribe" value="1" type="hidden"><input type="image" name="www" src="assets/templates/[template]/images/signup.jpg"></div>
</form>
<!--END: FRAME_MAILLIST-->
<div>
<style type="text/css">
                        div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li { 
                            float: left; 
                            width: 325px; 
                            height: 60px; 
} 
                        div.feedburnerFeedBlock { 
                            background-color:#FFFFFF;
                            padding:20px; 
                            color:#7A7A7A;
                            font-family:tahoma;
                            font-size:11px;
                        }
                        div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul {
                            margin-left:0px;
                            padding-left:0px;
                            list-style-type: square;
                        }
                        div.feedburnerFeedBlock ul li span.headline { 
                            font-size:16px;
                            font-weight:bold;
                            color:#000000;
                            text-decoration:none;
                            display:block; 
                            margin:5px 0 0 0; 
                        }
                        .headline a{ 
                            font-size:14px;
                            color:#000000;
                        }
                        .headline a:hover{ 
                            color:#DF01A5;
                        }
                        .feedTitle a{ 
                            font-size:16px;
                            font-weight:bold;
                            color:#000000;
                        }
                        .postlink{ 
                            font-size:11px;
                        }

                        div  #creditfooter{ 
                        display: none; 
                        } 
</style>
<script src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/LatestFromTheBlog?format=sigpro"     type="text/javascript" ></script>

</div></td>
<td align="left" valign="top"><a href=""><div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/braaapOnline" data-width="266" data-height="420" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="true">        </div>
</a></td>

<td align="right" valign="top"><a href=""><iframe src="http://snapwidget.com/in/?u=YnJhYWFwb25saW5lfGlufDEzNXwyfDN8fG5vfDV8bm9uZXxvblN0YXJ0fHllcw==&v=19913" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:266px; height: 420px" ></iframe></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

This is the code for the entire line, including the newsletter signup, blog feed, facebook and instragram

please help!!

Comment: Did you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site,...First I advice to change your table into something more semantic code wise like divs..

Then you can edit your iframe like box here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/

Try adding a smaller width, get the code, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apply these properties to the second `<td>` (the one that has Facebook Page feed)

```
position: absolute;
margin-left: -280px;
```

And as Riskbreaker says, you better use `Div` tags, as they cleaner, easy to deal with using CSS, specially in Your case as it seems to you are trying to give it a grid layout (system)